# Add fade in effect on onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i add fade in for this specefic code? I want the pictures to fade in on onload.
Have done some research on Stackoverflow, but couldn't find anything useful. Some help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
       var img = document.getElementById('img')
       if(img.clientHeight<$('#div').height()){
            img.style.height=$('#div').height()+"px";
       }
       if(img.clientWidth<$('#div').width()){
            img.style.width=$('#div').width()+"px";
       } 
}
</script>
```

Extra question: Is it also possible to add a load-function to this code?

Comment: Hey Sj, is there a reason your not using jQuery or some other DOM abstraction layer?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: @Slukehart no, not really. I found this solution, and it worked smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sj what your attempting to do can be simplified using jQuery.  jQuery is a JavaScript library that makes working with HTML documents much easier.

Here is a little fiddle demonstrating their fadeIn method: http://jsfiddle.net/zgRtd/3/

Just to make sure your clear on what's happening:

---

We declare a function named load Image - this function uses jQuery to attach the fadeIn method to our jQuery object (referenced with CSS Selectors).

The images are set to display: none; initially.

```
function loadImage () {
    $('#your-image').fadeIn('slow', function () {
        // Animation complete
    });
}
```

We call the function once the document is loaded (this could be bound to any event), I've commented this out in the JSFiddle example.

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    loadImage();
});
```

Comment: This is perfect, working smooth. Thank you. But, do you have any ideas how i can implement the code above?

Comment: So are you just not sure where to put the code?  You'll want to add it between a script tag at the bottom of the page <script></script>